# If condition in MVC by Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new in mvc5

I want to display error message for if the customer mobile number field that not available in database

I tried similarly with this
it works well for **first condition** but with for **else** doesn't

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#customer_mobile').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Cases/History_Test?searchMobile=' + $('#customer_mobile').val(),
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {

                if(true)
                {
                    var Output = "<h4 align=center> History of Cases for</h4>";
                    Output += "<table>"
                    Output += "<tr>"
                    Output += "<th>" + " Case ID &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;  </th>";
                    Output += "<th>" + " Case Name &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;  </th>";
                    Output += "<th>" + " Customer Name &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  </th>";
                    Output += "</tr>";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {
                        Output += "<tr>"
                        Output += "<td>" + "&nbsp" + data[i].case_id + "&nbsp; </td>";
                        Output += "<td>" + data[i].case_name + "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  </td>";
                        Output += "<td>" + data[i].customer_name + "&nbsp; </td>";
                        Output += "</tr>"
                    }

                    Output += "</table>"

                    //alert(Output);
                    $('#partView').html(Output);
                }
                else{
                    $('#customer_mobile').change(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Cases/Check_Customer?searchMobile=' + $('#customer_mobile').val(),
                            method: 'GET',
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert("Error this customer not avalibale ")
                            }
                            });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and my controller

```
    public ActionResult History_Test(string searchMobile)
    {
        var cases = from c in db.Case
                    select c;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchMobile))
            cases = cases.Where(c => c.Customer.customer_mobile.Contains(searchMobile));
        else
            cases = cases.Where(p => p.case_id == -1);
        return Json(cases.Select(d => new { case_id = d.case_id, case_name = d.case_name, customer_mobile = d.customer_mobile, customer_name = d.Customer.customer_name }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    public ActionResult Check_Customer(string CheckhMobile)
    {
        var cases = from c in db.Case
                    where c.customer_mobile==CheckhMobile
                    select c;

        if (cases.Count() > 0)
            return Json(new { existing  = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        else
            return Json(new { existing = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Not clear what your asking. Your `if('#customer_mobile' == true)` line of code makes no sense. What do you think your trying to do with that? And why do you have a `$('#customer_mobile').change(function () {` inside a `$('#customer_mobile').change(function () {`?

Comment: Hello Stephen, I want only check the phone number is it available in customer's database or no?

If yes, display the table of history 
If no , alert with error message

Comment: Not a lot of your code makes any sense. What are you trying to do with the `History_Test()` method? Are you wanting to make 2 ajax calls at the same time? You need to edit your question and explain step by step what you want your code to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Statement if(true) will always true and never execute the else statement.

Try This  this may help you:

```
if(data.length>0)
                    {
                        var Output = "<h4 align=center> History of Cases for</h4>";
                        Output += "<table>"
                        Output += "<tr>"
                        Output += "<th>" + " Case ID &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;  </th>";
                        Output += "<th>" + " Case Name &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;  </th>";
                        Output += "<th>" + " Customer Name &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  </th>";
                        Output += "</tr>";
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                        {
                            Output += "<tr>"
                            Output += "<td>" + "&nbsp" + data[i].case_id + "&nbsp; </td>";
                            Output += "<td>" + data[i].case_name + "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  </td>";
                            Output += "<td>" + data[i].customer_name + "&nbsp; </td>";
                            Output += "</tr>"
                        }

                        Output += "</table>"

                        //alert(Output);
                        $('#partView').html(Output);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#customer_mobile').change(function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/Cases/Check_Customer?searchMobile=' + $('#customer_mobile').val(),
                                method: 'GET',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    alert("Error this customer not avalibale ")
                                }
                                });
                        });
                    }
```

if data.length > 0 if statement will execute other wise else statement will execute